# usb 3 recognized as 2.1

Tags: usb, usb-3

im trying to connect my quest and ive tried flipping swapping rotating the ends of the cable and reinstalled different drivers for my mobo. ive disabled the power option and the other selective thing as well.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So many details missing: 1. which oculus device are you using? 2. which cable are you using? 3. did you try another USB port 4. did you try a different PC 5. do other USB3 devices work on this computer? etc.etc.etc. The more information you add, the higher the chances are that someone is able to help you. I can guarantee you that no volunteer  is willing to pull every bit of information out of your nose, as this is no paid support site. You need to be proactive if you expect someone to help you.